# .live('click',fn issue when used with traversal

Tags: jquery

OK so I have an element that is normally loaded no ajax, but then on click it reloads (along with other content) via ajax.  no I cannot make the click elements non-ajax loaded on click.

Everything is working fine except I am doing the following on the .live click event:

```
$('.product-sort a.type-a').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

Now the first time it works fine.  but then the by the second/third time depending on the element I click, it doesn't just remove type-a it also removes the active class from type-b elements... I did `console.log($('.product-sort a.type-a'))` and after ajax some of the elements are loading twice.  Is the solution to just simply ajax load the nav to begin with so there isn't a predom/postdom elements?  or is there another way around this?

Comment: Check this related question about events binding on dynamically created elements : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Just a side note. The `live` function was deprecated since version 1.7 and is removed in version 1.9. http://api.jquery.com/live/ --- Just so you know you run into trouble when you upgrade to the latest jQuery version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you applying the correct classes to the reloaded DOM elements, because the selector should not be failing if you are. It is possible that you apply `.type-a` class to anchors that should be `.type-b` or you're applying both classes.

Also one suggestion, `live()` is deprecated in `jQuery` 1.7 and removed in 1.9, use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: I really should refresh my knowledge base with these changes... thanks for the heads up, I'll take a look at moving over to 1.9 and seeing if that fixes the issue.  and yea for some reason, it still targets the other elements.. I use different data-type="type_1" for targeting, it's really an odd one..